# Some Menus look incorrect

Tags: 11.04, graphics, gnome

Can someone explain to me why a clean install of 11.04, x64 is having these strange menu issues? Example:

[image: Menu Example]

This seems to happen on a few "Right-Click" menus, and not all system menus are affected. Can someone give me hand on fixing this?

I am using `Ubuntu Classic` for my session

Comment: The panel context menus are using same "panel.png" image which is used for panel backgrounds, thus you'll face this problem particularly with Ambiance and Radiance themes, a well-written GTK theme (Eg; elementary, equinox evolution, etc) doesn't have any such issues. This problem also occurs when you resize the panel (in classic ubuntu) above 24px.

Comment: Is there anything that can be done about it in `Ubuntu Classic`?

Comment: Yes, if you have some knowledge about theme editing/creation. Since, the bug is in both Ambiance and Radiance themes. However, a quick n dirty workaround would be to create another "panel_bg.png" with same height and width (as in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/Gtk-2.0/panel_bg.png) but without any curvy shadow and replace it with original image and reload the theme, but that would also make your panels ugly. Though I have not tried it, I'd recommend you to go for other theme of your choice, and report this bug in Launchpad.

Comment: @Kush So where should I report this in Launchpad?

Comment: Since the bug is in both Ambiance and Radiance themes, it targets the package `light-themes` so you'll need to report it manually and provide as much details as possible. You can report bug on [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/light-themes) page. Before you report the bug, make sure you mention version of this package on launchpad, you can see version of this package installed in your computer using Synaptic Package Manager (System>Administration) and searching for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like I'll need to file a bug report. I'll get the details back here when I do.

Comment: Yes, I think it's a known bug though I don't know it's entry in the Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked mine, after having seen your posted pic, and found that mine are the same.  I did not notice this in Unity, but started experimenting with the **Classic** interface today.